# Why does ant hang after multithreaded junit test unless I call join?

Tags: java, multithreading, ant, junit

When I run one of my unit tests through my ant build file's junit target

```
<junit showoutput="true" printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes" fork="yes" timeout="60000">
```

junit shows me:

```
[junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.958 sec
```

indicating successful completion of the test, however, it hangs after that line and will sit there for indefinitely (until I kill it).

Within the test, a new thread is created, but based on `System.out.println` output, I can see that it never completes even though it shouldn't take more than a couple of seconds. If I explicitly call `join()` then everything completes as expected.

If I run the same junit test in Eclipse (without the explicit `join()`) nothing seems amiss.

My question is [why] do I need to call `join()` before my unit test's method returns?

Comment: Are you forking the tests in a new VM? And if so, is the thread that never finishes marked as a daemon thread?

Comment: I added the junit line. I seem to get the same behavior whether the thread the test creates is marked as daemon or not.

Comment: Also, I don't know if it matters, but I should add that the created thread loads native libraries. One is mine which doesn't use threads, and another is 3rd party (which they claim is thread-safe).

Comment: The forked VM won't finish unless all non-daemon threads have. I'm surprised the `timeout` doesn't kick in.